# As3 flash button in a movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

all I am trying to get a button I placed inside a movie clip to change the scene on my main timeline.

this is what I have right now:
on the main timeline,

the scene that has the movie clip is called (girl_tone_control) and the scene that I want to go to is called (girl_outfit_v1)

inside the movie clip on (girl_tone_control), I have a button on a frame with the instant name letsgo_btn.

I then have another layer in the same movie clip as the button called actions

with this code

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

letsgo_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, letsgo1);

function letsgo1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(1,'girl_outfit_v1');
}
```

I don't know if this is correct every time I test it out hoping to go to scene (girl_outfit_v1) it doesn't work and I get the error

```
ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene girl_outfit_v1 was not found.
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
at wwe2_girl_tone_control_fla::girl_select_1/letsgo1()
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to double check the scene name as it must work, or attach your fla to let me check what's wrong

Comment: I got it working!!. I had two: inpert flash.events.MouseEvent; line on the same frame, one on a different layer as I wanted to keep the codes separate so I can see properly. Just deleted one of them and it worked.

Comment: Sounds weird, you can have as much as possible imports, so it is hardly a reason. Anyway nice that it've helped you)

Comment: yes thank you for your help. I also found out that if my webcam is unpluged or not working, the scrips starts behaving weird as well. I do have a load web cam streem script aswell in the file. thanks to my work mate for switching the cam I was using with a broken one that looks the same and not telling me.